# Add new 'has many' entity without overriding existing ones

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to accomplish a very simple task using Cakephp and after a couple of days reading and trying I can't find the solution. I'll try to explain it as better as I can:

I have a simple 'has many' relationship between two entities ('Clients' and 'Notes'). A client has many notes.

I have the 'Edit' page for the client and I would like to have in that page this two functionalities:

- Read/View all the existing notes (readonly)
- Add new note

So, following the documentation and several examples, in my edit form I've written the following code to generate the new note input field:

```
<?= $this->Form->control( 'client_notes.0.text' ); ?>
```

This is working just fine if the client has no notes of course. But if the client has any note this field gets populated with the first note so it gets overwritten on the save action.

I've also tried a different approach with no luck either:

I've tried to add a different input field such as

```
<?= $this->Form->control( 'new_note' ); ?>
```

and then tried to create a new 'Note' entity on the ClientController but this is where I get most confused. Should I modify the requestData passed to the edit method? How is the best way to do this? I've read that modifying the requestData is no longer doable/advised in cakephp.

Last thing I've tried so far is doing that in the 'beforeMarshal' as I've seen out there but it seems I can't get it right, this is my code:

```
public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, ArrayObject $data, ArrayObject $options)
{
    if (isset($data['new_note'])) {
        $text = $data['new_note'];
        $data['client_notes'] = [
            ['text' => $text ]
        ];
    }
}
```

I'll appreciate any help or guidance. Not looking for the magical code to paste in my project but for learning how to do it as I may have to do similar things in my current project. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about counting the notes and replacing 0 in `$this->Form->control( 'client_notes.0.text' );`

Comment: simply remove or unset the notes from the `$client` entity before passing it to the form.

Comment: @marekful I thought of that but it may have some problems with recurency, for example if there are two users editing the same client, if one of them adds a note and then the other does the same, they will be using the same index so the note will be overwritten

Comment: @arilia Yes, I tried that too bu how I get the notes to show them in the same page then?

Comment: there are plenty of ways: you can save the entity (without the notes) in a variable and store the notes in another variable. Or you can use two entities (one with the notes and the second without). Or you can create the form after the notes list so that you can unset the client_notes array...

Comment: @arilia I feel quite dumb right now. Never thought of using two entities or two variables from the controller. I'll give it a try. Thanks